What is the power of the test?
There are $n$ cards in an urn labelled $1$ through $n$, where $1\leq n\leq 5$ is an unknown integer parameter. The null hypothesis $H_0: n=5$ and $H_1: n\leq 4$. We reject $H_0$ if we draw two cards with replacement and both have a number smaller than 3 on them. What is the power of this test?
If $H_1$ is true than $n\leq 4$, which is the same as $n=1,2,3,4$. Now $\mathbb{P}(X_{1,2}<3|n\leq 4)=\frac{1}{4}(\mathbb{P}(X_{1,2}<3|n=1)+\mathbb{P}(X_{1,2}<3|n=2)+\mathbb{P}(X_{1,2}<3|n=3)+\mathbb{P}(X_{1,2}<3|n=4))=\frac{1}{4}(1+1+\frac{4}{9}+\frac{1}{4})$
But it doesn't seem right to me.

Do we have some prior probability distribution for the $n$ or a particular “effect size” (i.e. $n$) we are interested in? $P(-\mid n\le 4)$ does not make sense from a frequentist perspective (and if it did, that’s not the way to calculate it).

Uniform, I reckon. So, is it the law of total probability?

Is it okay now?

@spaceisdarkgreen Sorry, forgot to tag.

It would be something like $$P(D\mid n\le 4)P(n\le 4) = P(D\mid n=1)P(n=1)+ P(D\mid n=2)P(n=2)+\ldots$$
(I think that is the same thing as dividing by $4$. Also I don't know why you're saying prob 0 for the first one and prob 1 for the second one... they are both 1.)

@spaceisdarkgreen Why do you need $\mathbb{P}(n\leq 4)$, though?

Because then the LHS the same thing as the total probability that the data happened while $n\le 4.$ I see you used $1/4$ rather than $1/5$ as the probabilities on the RHS though, so that's doing the same thing.

Like i could have written $$ P(D\mid n\le 4) = P(D\mid n=1)P(n=1\mid n\le 4) + P(D\mid n=2)P(n=2\mid n\le 4)+\ldots$$ instead. And then all the weights on the RHS are 1/4 and there's no weight on the LHS.

As you have already been informed, the power of the test depends on the specific parameter $n$; it cannot be calculated for a set of values, in your case $n \le 4$.
One way to resolve this is to take a Bayesian approach and impose a prior probability distribution on $n$, at which point you can compute a "power" by weighting the conditional probabilities of rejecting the null by the prior probability of $n$ for each $n \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.
An alternate approach is to compute a power function $1-\beta(n)$ that gives the power of the test for each specific value of $n$ contained in the alternative hypothesis.  In particular, we would compute
$$1-\beta(n^*) \Pr[X_{1,2} < 3 \mid n = n^*]$$
for each $n^* \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.  I think you can proceed with the calculations.
Another approach is to compute the greatest lower bound of the power under the condition $n \le 4$, which guarantees that your test has at least this much power.  But this does not furnish as much information as the power function itself.
